# Using PDO database class within other PHP classes

Tags: php

I have a database class that uses PDO. Here's a portion example of it:

```
class db {
private $host;
private $username;
private $password;
private $con;
    private $pdo;

public function __construct( $database = "dnname" )
{
    $this->host = "localhost";
    $this->username = "username";
    $this->password = "pass";
            $conStr = "host={$this->host};dbname={$database}";
            try {
                $this->pdo = new PDO( "mysql:$conStr", $this->username, $this->password );
                $this->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            }
            catch( PDOException $e ) {
                echo "error ". $e->getMessage();
            }
}

public function fetch_single_row($sql, $data)
{
    if( $data !== null )
        $data = array_values( $data ); // Incase it's an associative array
    $sel = $this->pdo->prepare( $sql );
    $sel->execute( $data );
    $sel->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
    $obj = $sel->fetch();
    return $obj;
}
```

I would like to use this class and its functions (it has more than I've included) inside other classes.

I have tried many many different things, but the only thing *that works* so far is starting a new instance of db in every new class which **I think is bad practice**. For instance:

```
class cms {
   function cms(){
       $this->db = new db();
   }

   function is_admin($id) {
    if($this->db->fetch_single_row("SELECT id FROM user WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1", array($id))){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

in my index.php, I include these classes and use them:

```
include("db.class.php");
include("cms.class.php");

$cms = new cms();

if($cms->is_admin($id)){
   //code here
}
```

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Should your db class's variables be static? It would alleviate most, if not all, performance issues regarding multiple instantiation. In fact, you could just not instantiate a new instance of your db class, but use static functions of your class.

Comment: __Construct cannot be static, according to php error reporting :)

Comment: Well, since it's static, you'll only ever need to call any constructing code once. Therefore, explicitly calling a pseudo-constructor after defining the class will do it for you. (But I agree with `__construct` not being static.)

Comment: I apologize, I am unsure what you mean. Do you mean changing all the functions in my db class to static, except for the __construct()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look into the Singleton Design Pattern, it works great for a DB class

I used to use a class like this for quite a while

```
   abstract class DB
   {

    protected static $instance;

    protected $db;

    protected static $host = 'host';
    protected static $user = 'user';
    protected static $pass = 'pass';
    protected static $database;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new static();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', static::$host, static::$database), static::$user, static::$pass);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public static function db()
    {
        return static::getInstance()->db;
    }

    public function fetch_single_row($sql, $data)
    {
        if( $data !== null )
            $data = array_values( $data ); // Incase it's an associative array
        $sel = self::db()->prepare( $sql );
        $sel->execute( $data );
        $sel->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
        $obj = $sel->fetch();
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

I would then extend that class for each different database I would need to connect to

```
class Main extends DB
{
    protected static $database = 'db';
}
```

You can then use the class like this

```
$db = Main::getInstance();
$obj = $db->fetch_single_row($sql, $data);
```

Comment: Whenever you need an instance of the database connection in your application, just call `$db = Main::getInstance();` and continue using `$db` to perform queries

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this line:
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new static();

Comment: I get `FATAL ERROR: Call to protected method db::getInstance() from context 'cms' ` when trying to call `$this->db = db::getInstance();` inside my cms class

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? The static keyword is late static binding and is available in php 5.3+. So if you are using an older version, then a quick fix is by not makign it an abstract class

Comment: sorry, make the getInstance function public.  I have updated my code

Comment: after you make the getInstance function public it should work fine. I just tested it

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your help, but I cannot get passed the php errors. Could you provide example of usage in another class? such as my example above?

Also the line `if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new static();` gives errors in dreamweaver. Is it supposed to be `if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new db();`?

Comment: I updated my code providing an example. I put your function in the base class and shown how to use it. I tested the code and it works fine. No that line is suppose to be the way it is, this is late static binding. I just ran the code myself and it worked fine